# How to use firebase v9 signInWithCredential correctly with OAuthProvider?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Apple Sign In with firebase's v9 modular signInWithCredential function.

I've been following the documentation on both firebase & apple side but keep getting the following error when I try to run signInWithCredential:

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'credential._getIdTokenResponse')]

I am able to get the Apple Sign In to pop-up & use a biometric to authenticate. This then gives me an identityToken that I've verified on jwt.io. It's only at signInWithCredentials where it throws an error.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
        const appleCredential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
            requestedScopes: [
                AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
                AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL
            ],
            state: csrf,
            nonce: hashedNonce
        });
        const { identityToken, authorizationCode } = appleCredential;
        if (identityToken) {

            const authCredential = new OAuthProvider(
                "apple.com"
            ).credential({
                idToken: identityToken,
                accessToken: authorizationCode,
                rawNonce: nonce // nonce value from above
            });

            signInWithCredential(authCredential)
                .then((credential) => {
                    console.log(credential?.providerId)

                }).catch(e => { console.log("error in apple auth: ", e) })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding auth as the first argument to signInWithCredential, i.e.,

```
signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
```

where auth = getAuth(app).
See also: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth?hl=en#signinwithcredential